# Module '"react-popper"' has no exported member 'usePopper' #424

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-popper

Packages versions
react-popper: "react-popper": "^2.2.5",

we used it in our custom-ui-kit project, and we were able to fix the error in that project, but we still have problems in the project it's used in.

Comment: in node-module its imported but in import line has err
import { usePopper } from 'react-popper';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the correct version of this package in the used package first
Second, publish it and make sure you're using the latest version
Install popper in this project again if your problem persists